# Could not expand ZIP, how can i solve this error?

Tags: java, android-studio, zip, expand, android-studio-2.2

everytime i create a new project in Android Studio I'm getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72510Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\appcompat-v7-25.1.0.aar'.
```

I cant find a good solution in the internet.

Rebuilding, cleaning and restarting the project doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Follow this, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229171, seems like in a multi threaded process, when a thread was trying to unzip the file it was being locked by another thread. At the very bottom it is suggested to 'Compile independent modules in parallel' by enabling that opriton in Settings (#14 ian.hannibal.lake) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the `aar` file using file system.

This `appcompat-v7-25.1.0.aar` could be broken in cache (e.g. due to connection drop, etc.)